# SQL Execute Statement for Create Procedure in multiple databases

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am running a loop which iterates through a bunch of databases and among several commands there is one that installs a procedure. I am having a problem with this. I have tried a few methods but they error.

```
*'use '+@DBName+';
            CREATE proc [dbo].proc_ContributorTapHistoryUpdate ....*
```

> Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 'CREATE PROCEDURE' must be the
>   first statement in a query batch.

```
*CREATE proc '+@DBName+'.[dbo].proc_ContributorTapHistoryUpdate .....*
```

> Msg 166, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 'CREATE PROCEDURE' does not allow
>   specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name.

Code Sample:

```
declare @DBName varchar(20)

declare ProjectList cursor FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY for

select name as DBName
from sysdatabases
where isnumeric(substring(name,4,40)) = 1

open ProjectList

fetch next from ProjectList
into @DBName

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

execute('use '+@DBName+' go 
    CREATE proc [dbo].proc_ContributorTapHistoryUpdate
    as
    begin
        select * from sysobjects where name = ''FU''
    end
')
if @@ERROR <> 0
    goto ERR_EXIT
fetch next from ProjectList
into @DBName
end

ERR_EXIT:

close ProjectList

deallocate ProjectList
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3441031/SQL-Server-Undocumented-Stored-Procedures-spMSforeachtable-and-spMSforeachdb.htm You can replace the db's name with "?"

Comment: Add `GO` after `USE`?

Comment: The key words "Use" and "Go" are not allowed in the command. The procedure must be the first statement in the query batch. Thanks anyway both Shnugo and Nick.

Comment: Use registered servers, register your databases and run simple script on multiple targets at once.

Comment: I found a solution!!! The idea is to Use the DB and then in an execute statement within create the procedure.

Comment: set @Command = 'USE '+@DestinationDB+' ; 
EXEC('''+replace(@BaseCreateProcedure,char(39),char(39)+char(39))+''')' 
exec(@Command)